# Create tiles for leaflet.js

Tags: tiles

All I am trying to do is create map tiles from an image to be used on a webiste. The only program I have found to do this is MapTiler, however it adds a watermark. Does anyone know how I can create them without any watermarks?

Comment: gdaltools and ogrtools are open source toolsets that can do this. QGIS uses them, so the answer below is also valid.

Answer (score 0):

The QGIS plugin `QTiles` can produce tiles from a QGIS project, so if you load your image as a raster RGB layer you can use `QTiles` to produce sets of tiles at different zoom levels that span your image file.

Comment: allright I'll try that. thanks